# Load default value for a comboBox extjs

Tags: javascript, combobox, extjs, store

how can i load a default value from my json store (remote) into a combobox , 
i've tried load the store before render the combo , and use setValue() 
i want my combo to display the first result in the store 
plz tell me the right way to do this and thanx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extjs 4 combobox default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965416/extjs-4-combobox-default-value)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to set the `value` property to the value of the first element after the store is loaded

```
Ext.ns('MyNamespace');

MyNamespace.MyComboBox = Ext.extend(Ext.form.ComboBox, {
  displayField: 'displayValue',
  triggerAction: 'all',
  valueField: 'ID',

  initComponent: function () {
    this.store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
      url: 'url',
      baseParams: {
        //params
      },
      fields: [
        {name:'ID', mapping: 'ID', type: 'int'},
        {name:'displayValue', mapping: 'displayValue', type: 'string'},
      ],
      root: 'root'
    });

    var me = this;
    this.store.on('load',function(store) {
      me.setValue(store.getAt(0).get('ID'));
    })

    MyNamespace.MyComboBox.superclass.initComponent.call(this);

    this.store.load();
  }

});
```