# Extjs combo default Value?

Tags: extjs, combobox

```
                               {
                                            xtype:'combo',
                    name : 'policyId',
                    fieldLabel : 'policyTyep',
                    padding : 'padding-left: 20%',
                    displayField : 'analysisName',
                    valueField : 'analysisId',
                    queryMode : 'local',
                    //value:-1,
                    value: {analysisName:'Select..',
                            analysisId:0},
                    store : policyDetailTypeStore
                }
                       If I the policyDetailTypeStore is loaded ,but have no data.
```

then I want to show "Select..." in the combox.I also have configure the value as the code, but Can't work at all..

Comment: just 'Select' is enough in value config(value:'Select...')

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extjs 4 combobox default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965416/extjs-4-combobox-default-value)

Answer (score 7):

you should actually be using the `emptyText` config attribute for this

```
{
   ...
   emptyText : 'Select ...',
   ...
}
```